# Properties are not read from Vault on Integrating Vault with Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I am trying use Spring boot config server with git and vault and all my spring boot client application will retrieve the vault properties via the config server by passing the vault config token.

I am using the spring boot 2.1.8.RELEASE and below is the POM.xml file for my spring boot config server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.ps.psc</groupId>
<artifactId>psc-config-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>psc-config-server</name>
<description>Spring configuration server</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
    - git
    - vault
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      server:
        git:
          order: 2
          username: ********
          password: ********
          uri: https://*******@bitbucket.org/krushna/configuration.git
          search-paths:
          - payment*
        vault:
          host: 127.0.0.1
          port: 8200
          scheme: http
          order: 1
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          kv-version: 1
    vault:
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: s.PB5cAJ9WhOuWamIOuFVkzpbl
      scheme: http
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8200
      config:
        order: 1
```

My application.yml file

```
server:
 port: 7000
spring:
  application:
  name: configserver
```

With the above configuartion my config server is able read the properties only from the GIT not from the vault.

In the vault I have written a properties like below.

```
vault write secret/payment password=test@123
```

If I make curl call like below

```
curl -X "GET" "http://127.0.0.1:7000/payment/default" -H "X-Config-Token: s.PB5cAJ9WhOuWamIOuFVkzpbl"
```

I am geeting properties from git only, response below.

```
{
"name": "payment",
"profiles": ["default"],
"label": null,
"version": "e9b941d22f6b7cd3083a731d168f78fa4ec0fc42",
"state": null,
"propertySources": [{
    "name": "https://******@bitbucket.org/krushna/configuration.git/application.properties",
    "source": {
        "foofromGit": "bar"
    }
}]
}
```

What I am doing worng here? I have tried multiple option like differnt KV version, only configuring spring cloude config vault etc.

Edit:

I have used the vault conf like below.

```
backend "file" {
    path = "vault"
}
listener "tcp" {
    tls_disable = 1
}
```

and doing curl to vault driectly I am able to read the value now.

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Vault-Token:s.PB5cAJ9WhOuWamIOuFVkzpbl" http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/payment/
```

response:

```
{
    "request_id": "35c8793e-3530-81c1-7917-3e922ef4065b",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 2764800,
    "data": {
        "password": "test@123"
    },
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null
}
```

Comment: What happen if you you comment `git settings`? are you getting `vault properties` only?

Comment: I just saw an error of typo `- valut` change to `vault`,  is this the issue in your  properties? @Krushna

Comment: @JonathanJohx Thanks corrected it but the issue is not solved

Comment: is the vault scheme http or https?

Comment: @Krushna, did you try the first comment that I did? if you don't have retrieve some property means that is not connecting on your `URL` properly.

Comment: @JonathanJohx  removing the git from the active profile and git configuration I am getting error like "Description:

Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration."

Comment: @Santos, it is on http, BTW, try to curl to vault server directly like this : curl -X GET -H "X-Vault-Token:s.PB5cAJ9WhOuWamIOuFVkzpbl" http://localhost:8200/v1/secret/payment/ and I am getting error like "1 error occurred:\n\t* read failed: decryption failed: cipher: message authentication failed\n\n", is this related to that spring is not able read from vault

Comment: @Santos if do curl with 127.0.0.1 it is working, i am able to get the data directly from vault, but through config server, the questions is updated with latest edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix the issue by moving the git and spring cloude config vault configuration details from bootstrap.yml to application.yml like below.

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: s.jyFarEyroi5pJNOxPnhT4f3D
      scheme: http
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8200
      config:
        order: 1
```

Application.yml

```
server:
  port: 7000
spring:
  profiles:
    active: git, vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://krushna@bitbucket.org/krushna/configuration.git
          search-paths:
          - payment*
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.01
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          scheme: http
```

I am still not clear how this fix the issues?, only thing I know that bootstrap will load first, and I am reading the git credential from vault and then application.yml has the other details for the spring cloud config vault and git.

Any explanation on this will be really welcome